# Codeigniter 2.0.3 with SQL Server Active Record

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I'm working on upgrading a Codeigniter app I have running on 1.7.2 to 2.0.3 but I'm not able to connect to SQL Server .  Both versions are running on the same server running php 5.2.10 and connecting to the same SQL Server.

This is the error from CI 2.0.3

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/Loader.php
Line Number: 260
```

This is the connection string I'm using which of course works on 1.7.2

```
$db['reports']['hostname'] = "mysqlserver";
$db['reports']['username'] = "sqluser";
$db['reports']['password'] = "sqlpass";
$db['reports']['database'] = "SQLReportDB";
$db['reports']['dbdriver'] = "mssql";
$db['reports']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['reports']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['reports']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['reports']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['reports']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['reports']['port']     = 972;
```

In the controller I call the connection with this

```
$report_db = $this->load->database('reports', TRUE);
```

Below is the function in the loader file where it reports the failure.
Line 260 is `return DB($params, $active_record);`

```
/**
 * Database Loader
 *
 * @param   string  the DB credentials
 * @param   bool    whether to return the DB object
 * @param   bool    whether to enable active record (this allows us to override the config setting)
 * @return  object
 */
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
{
    // Grab the super object
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // Do we even need to load the database class?
    if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');

    if ($return === TRUE)
    {
        return DB($params, $active_record);
    }

    // Initialize the db variable.  Needed to prevent
    // reference errors with some configurations
    $CI->db = '';

    // Load the DB class
    $CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an actual connection error. Double check the credentials? Anything in the sql server logs?

Comment: try to set $db['reports']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

Comment: Tried setting $db['reports']['pconnect'] = FALSE.  No change.

Comment: I obviously changed my connection information above to generic settings, but from 1.7.2 to 2.0.3 I'm copying and pasting the database connection settings.  No chance for typo :)  Same servers so no chance of firewall or network issues.

Comment: It looks as though 2.0.3 no longer takes the port setting

    $db['reports']['port']     = 972;

I removed that line and changed the server connection to include the port

    $db['reports']['hostname'] = "mysqlserver.example.com:972";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$db['reports']['port'] is no longer valid

The port needs to be added to the end of the server

$db['reports']['hostname'] = "mysqlserver:972";

Answer (score 0):

Here are some settings I use in connecting to a SQL Server you haven't listed. Might be required due to upgrade...

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: I did notice these few extra settings and added them on as well but no change.